# Correct way to specify type for storage in attached property?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, attached-properties

I have implemented an attached property keeping a System.Type value which works fine in WPF but throws an

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException

when used in an WinRT App. I'm guessing that the specified type can´t be resolved.

Here is the implementation of the attached property:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
#if NETFX_CORE
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
#else
using System.Windows;
#endif

namespace Test
{
    public class AttachedClass
    {
    }

    public static class PropaClass
    {
        public static Type GetAttachedType(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Type)obj.GetValue(AttachedTypeProperty);
        }

        public static void SetAttachedType(DependencyObject obj, Type value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(AttachedTypeProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachedTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AttachedType",
            typeof(Type), typeof(PropaClass), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnAttachedTypeChanged));

        private static void OnAttachedTypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Set value : {0}", e.NewValue.ToString(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how it's used in an WPF application:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:test="clr-namespace:Test"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    test:PropaClass.AttachedType="{x:Type test:AttachedClass}">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

And the WinRT App Page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:test="using:Test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    test:PropaClass.AttachedType="test:AttachedClass">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The exception I get in the WinRT App is:

```
Exception:Thrown: "Det gick inte att hitta texten som associeras med den här felkoden.

Failed to create a '%1' from the text '%0'. [Line: 10 Position: 5]" (Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException)
A Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException was thrown: "Det gick inte att hitta texten som associeras med den här felkoden.

Failed to create a '%1' from the text '%0'. [Line: 10 Position: 5]"
WinRT information: Failed to create a '%1' from the text '%0'. [Line: 10 Position: 5]
Time: 2015-03-19 12:05:00
Thread:<No Name>[396]
```

So my question is: What am I doing wrong? It works like a charm if I replace `test:PropaClass.AttachedType="test:AttachedClass">` with `test:PropaClass.AttachedType="test:PropaClass">` in the WinRT Page XAML!

Is there a way I can get the XAML parser to recognize AttachedClass?

P.S. This is using VS2013 targeting .NET framework 4.5 and Windows8.1

### Edit:

Adding this to the WinRT XAML Page removed the exception.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <test:AttachedClass x:Key="test"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

So "introducing" the type to the parser seems to correct the issue. However, this is not a valid workaround since I want to be able to use non-instantiable types.

I´m starting to lean towards a parser bug ...

### Another Edit:

I finally found a viable workaround; adding an empty style targeting the type you want to put in the attached property.

Adding the resource below gets rid of the exception.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="test:AttachedClass"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

This solution allows me to specify interfaces or abstract base classes as types to go into the attached property too.

Comment: For the english speakers, google translate says the error message at the start of the exception is: "Could not find the text associated with this error code"

Comment: That translation is correct, sorry for the omission!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried out the workaround defined in "Another Edit" above and it works well. I'll post it as an answer since it solves my issue and no other answers have been posted.

This issue is most likely due to a bug in the XAML parser that causes it to fail to resolve the type using the name provided. If the type is introduced to the parser in an alternative way it is recognized just fine. The way I use to introduce the type is to define an empty, unused style targeting the type to store in the attached property.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="test:AttachedClass"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

This way any type can be stored in the property.